# shiny server cannot be started after restart

Tags: ubuntu, shiny-server

I installed Shiny-server on Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It worked until I first restarted the machine. I'm not sure what's going on because I double-checked the config files and tweaked some params and yet I cannot have it running. So, I decided to reinstalled it but still no luck.

[image]

shiny-server.service

```
[Unit]
Description=ShinyServer

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=10
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server --pidfile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1'
# Needed to give SS a chance to write out to the PID file.
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3
PIDFile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid
Type=simple

Environment="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 5
RestartSec=1


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

shiny-server.conf

```
# Define the user we should use when spawning R Shiny processes
run_as shiny;

# Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  listen 3838;

  # Define the location available at the base URL
  location / {
    #### PRO ONLY ####
    # Only up tp 20 connections per Shiny process and at most 3 Shiny processes
    # per application. Proactively spawn a new process when our processes reach 
    # 90% capacity.
    utilization_scheduler 20 .9 3;
    #### END PRO ONLY ####

    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Define where we should put the log files for this location
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # Should we list the contents of a (non-Shiny-App) directory when the user 
    # visits the corresponding URL?
    directory_index on;
  }
}


# Setup a flat-file authentication system. {.pro}
auth_passwd_file /etc/shiny-server/passwd;

# Define a default admin interface to be run on port 4151. {.pro}
admin 4151 {
  # Only permit the user named `admin` to access the admin interface.
  required_user admin;
}
```

shiny-server.log

```
[32m[2017-11-01 01:01:43.874] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mShiny Server v1.5.5.872 (Node.js v6.10.3)
[32m[2017-11-01 01:01:43.878] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mUsing pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid
[32m[2017-11-01 01:01:43.879] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[31m[2017-11-01 01:01:43.925] [ERROR] shiny-server - [39mError loading config: Unknown directive "utilization_scheduler" (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:15:5)
[32m[2017-11-01 01:01:43.926] [INFO] shiny-server - [39mShutting down worker processes
```

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem: worked fine until I rebooted the server and now nothing.

Comment: @ jogall no, sorry man.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is caused by attempting to use a feature of R Studio Pro in the free version. Just comment out all those pro-only options if you do not have the pro version.